# Got after upgrading ruby: Symbol not found: __ZN6libdap5ErrorD1Ev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

It's been hours that I'm trying to understand the error but I don't get it.

I have tried to upgrade my ruby version from 2.5 to 2.7.4

I first update `rbenv` from `brew` then install the 2.7.4 version and used `rbenv rehash`

But now whenever I launch `rails c` or `rails s`, I've got the following errors:

```
Loading development environment variables
 - load /Users/myself/Work/my-app/.env
/Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': dlopen(/Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/gdal-ruby-1820e1643725/lib/gdal-ruby/gdal.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: __ZN6libdap5ErrorD1Ev
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.28.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/libdap/lib/libdap.27.dylib
 in /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.28.dylib - /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/gdal-ruby-1820e1643725/lib/gdal-ruby/gdal.bundle (LoadError)
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems/gdal-ruby-1820e1643725/lib/gdal.rb:2:in `<main>'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
    from /Users/myself/Work/my-app/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    from /Users/myself/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
```

I have tried to reinstall rbenv from brew but didn't work, I have spent hours to try to understand what this error means but as a beginner I don't get it.

What should I look for ?

EDIT: It's not from bootsnap since I've got the same problem if I remove bootsnap

Comment: Are you running `rails c` from within an existing project? What happens if you start a new Rails project?

Comment: Yes I run it from an existing project. I just try to create a new rails project and then run `rails c` and its working correctly.

Comment: Some dependencies of your existing gems may have been updated during an (implicit) `brew upgrade` run. You could try to re-install all gems of your project with `bundle pristine`

Comment: It worked with `bundle pristine` add it as an answer if you want then I can validate your answer :) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some dependencies of your existing gems may have been updated during an (implicit) `brew upgrade` run as you installed additional software.

When installing gems which use library dependencies (such as `libgdal` in your case), those gems may sometimes need to be re-compiled if the underlying library has changed in incompatible ways.

As such, a common first attempt to fix this to re-install the affected gem. If you use bundler, you can re-install all gems of your project by running

```
bundle pristine
```

This should ensure that your bundler-managed gems all use the latest versions of your libraries. See [the documentation of `bundle pristine`](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-pristine.1.html) for details of what this command does under the hood.